# Why do these two code pieces not produce the same output?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, internet-explorer-7

What I'm trying to do is produce the same thing twice with this code. The objective is to have 'Test prompt:' appear on the left, then a textbox to the right of it, then finally a 16x16 pixel box directly to the right of that.

In the HTML generation stage, I'm successful, but I'm trying to produce this entirely in javascript in a format that works in older web browsers such as Internet Explorer 7. I tested it on my computer in a newer browser (opera 11) and it turns out that the 16x16 pixel box is directly underneath the prompt. How do I go about fixing this?

```
<h2>HTML generation of the form</h2>
<form>
  <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%">
    <b style="float:left;background:#777">Test prompt:</b>
    <input type="text" style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left;background:#AAA;width:16px;height:16px"></div>
  </div>
</form>
<h2>Javascript generation of the same form</h2>
<!-- This phase does not work correctly -->
<div ID="CONTAINER">
</div>

<script>
  c=document.getElementById('CONTAINER'); //get container
  f=document.createElement('FORM'); //make form

  d=document.createElement('DIV'); //make containing DIV
  ds=d.style;
  ds.overflow='hidden';
  ds.width='100%';

  b=document.createElement('B'); //make prompt label
  b.innerHTML='Test prompt:';    //and set prompt
  bs=b.style;
  bs.float='left';
  bs.background='#777';

  i=document.createElement('INPUT'); //make textbox
  i.type='text'; //<-- not sure if I need this
  i.style.float='left';

  ed=document.createElement('DIV'); //Make 16x16 box
  eds=ed.style;
  eds.float='left'; 
  eds.background='#AAA';
  eds.width='16px';
  eds.height='16px';

  c.appendChild(f);//add form
  f.appendChild(d); //ad container div

  d.appendChild(b); //add prompt
  d.appendChild(i); //add textbox
  d.appendChild(ed); //add square box
</script>
```

Comment: FWIW, the code works great in Chrome (on Ubuntu)

Comment: @JoeAndrieu Yup, and in Safari, tried it in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zrrvxkp0/

Comment: And it worked fine in a freshly installed Opera 34

Comment: It must be browser issues then. I ended up having to declare the float in a class and then use that in javascript

Comment: FYI - Works fine in firefox 43 and 45, Chrome 47, Internet Explorer 5,7,8,9,10 and 11 and Edge 13 - some older browsers had strange layout issues if you never *clear* floated elements - but not the issue you describe (and nobody can reproduce)